# Does CSS Module generate same class name everytime for a particular css class defined in module

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-modules

I have defined below classes in my css module

```
.container-styles {
  height: 20px;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: rgb(128 , 128 , 128);
}

.filler-styles {
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: inherit;
  background-color: rgb(27, 150, 40);
  text-align: right;
}

.label-styles {
  padding: 5px;
  color: rgb(255 , 255 , 255);
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

In my developer tool I can see above name changes to below class name
**1 .container-styles => DocumentsStatuBar_container-styles__7vf23
2 .filler-styles =>  DocumentsStatuBar_filler-styles__6Imtl**  and so on

My question here is does these dynamically generated names will remain same evertime I build/run/test my project

Comment: I suppose they will change

Answer (score 0):

They will change everytime you build the project. For your use case you need to select it as a class. You need to import the styles file in your test file and then use it like this:

```
document.querySelector(`.${styles.container-styles}`)
```

Comment: I'm trying to write unit test case , by selecting the elements based on the classNames as of now shown below , so how should i approach for this now , if these names keep changes .  const gridClass = " .DocumentStatusPanel_error__OV2SI";
const fundClass = `${gridClass} > .DocumentStatusPanel_items__PtNVF`;
const currentTime = `${gridClass} > .DocumentStatusPanel_text__i4gGy`;